# How to update Java 7 to Java 8 in Google compute engine

Tags: java, java-8, google-compute-engine

I have tried following their documentations but to avail. Can anybody guide me the way so that I can proceed with the deployment?
I tried

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

but when I check the Java version it still shows `java 1.7.011`

Comment: You have to set java8 as the "selected" java version